# django provide same session everywhere

Tags: django, session, unique, shared

I'm working on a django app which use an external base to authenticate user.
After login, some informations are retrieved to the session.
The issue is that this initialized session is the same with the same session_id whatever the browser or the desktop I use without re-authenticate...

**authentication**:

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        login = request.POST["login"]
        password = request.POST["password"]
        #do something to authenticate by requesting an url
        request.session['infos'] = #infos string recieved
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('WebSite:index'))
```

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES contains django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.db"

INSTALLED_APPS contains django.contrib.sessions

An other effect of this is that after being authenticated somewhere, I get a CSRF failure when I try elsewhere...

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: I don't seem to understand what to need to achieve or know. Please specify more.

Comment: I may be didn't discribe well enough my probleme but clearly my question is: why each visitor of my website haven't his own session? How could I do for each visitor to have his own session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was in the cache:

The cache made django provide the same cookie at every request with the same session_id. So I deactivacted it until I set the cache with better settings.